# Install NumPy for W10

Tags: python

I want to install NumPy for Python 3.4 on W10. I used next process:

```
- download numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
- installation from folder which constaints *.whl and I used pip install *.whl
- I obtained message: *.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install NumPy on W10:

- run cmd as administrator
- in that window type: pip install numpy

Comment: Thank You! Why must I  file name replace by "numpy"?

Comment: Numpy is not a file name but name of the package that pip downloads and installs (it has nothing to do with wheel you've downloaded earlier)